# EF Core: auto-generated custom format sequence number

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

How can I achieve a auto-generated column using EF Core Code First.

Here are some of output I want to achieve:

```
ColumnCode

2019-1
2019-2
2019-3
...
2019-10
```

When I inserted a row with a transaction date of 2020 will generate something like this:

```
ColumnCode

2020-1
2020-2
...
2020-10
```

And I can also add previous year transaction like:

```
ColumnCode

2018-1
2018-2
...
2017-1
2016-1
```

etc...

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem, Why do you need to do this?

Comment: It will use for control number of form/report to be printed.

Comment: I'm thinking to use HasComputedColumnSql but I don't know how to achieve that, to get the  max count of the transaction date year.

Comment: This should likely be the concern of the query that prints reports and normalized data you have in the table which can be indexed appropriately. Forcing a clustered index to use this regime may lead to other issues

Comment: If I compute in c# get the max count using the transaction date year and I will append max count in transaction date year so I can produce the ColumnCode value but my concern is Concurrency that will cause duplicate entry. I don't kwon if that is a good practice

Comment: If you have an incremental PK, and a date. you don't need this code, unless in the very rare occasion where you need to visually display it on an invoice or something before it is saved (or something very weird like that), even though there are still better approaches then to make this regime a PK

Comment: I need a column that resetting every year

Comment: I suppose you have to calculate it youself, especially because at some point of time that would be required to insert a new item for previous year. And the column you designed initially contradicts to the [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: Can I calculate using code in c# fetching the max count of transaction year then saving it? My worry is when you save parallel processing/concurrency that may cause duplicate entry